# Is a website legitimate that offers to double your deposit within 7 days?

Tags: exchanges

Anybody familiar with this website?

https://www.investyourbitcoin.net

I really want to work with them but I can't seem to find any review about it online?

It seems legit.. but is it legit?

Answer (score 1):

**Any website or service that promises to 'double your coins' is almost certainly a scam. Do not send them any bitcoin, or any other form of money.**

Think about it this way:

- Any sort of trading is a zero-sum game, *there is not an infinite amount of BTC out there, to continuously double everyone's coins to infinity*. Any trading strategy / whatever this website claims to do in order to double your coins, will involve a counterparty to the trade. Where else would they get the bitcoins from?
- With that in mind, if you were the website operator, and you actually had a fool-proof method to double up bitcoin, would you use it to double *your* money, or offer your service to others, to double *their* money? Your method cannot work infinitely, since it is a zero-sum game. So why let someone else take advantage of your method, instead of using it yourself?

The answer to this should be obvious: there is no 'foolproof way to double bitcoins'. Anyone claiming to have one is just trying to scam you.

Comment: Darn... Just too late.. After 10 minutes I left this site to go check it out some more and I did put in a small investment just now.. But I really understand your explination that's what's bothering me right now..

Comment: On the other hand.. I did just get a confirmation e-mail that looks legit !

Comment: Scam sites will often look legit, until they run away with your money. In some cases they will even work to build up trust, giving you returns on small deposits, and then later stealing a large deposit. My sincere advice is to never again send them money, and in the meantime hope that you have your deposit returned.

Comment: @Bivakboy, the investyourbitcoin.net domain ("making money for you since 2016"!)  was [registered only yesterday](https://reports.internic.net/cgi/whois?whois_nic=investyourbitcoin.net&type=domain). Its a clone of https://coin2x.me - another suspected ponzi fraud.